# Intellij IDEA won't start anymore after cpu profiler is enabled

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 x64 on windows 10.
I wanted to attach CPU profiler according to this:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems#CPU_Snapshot_2019_2

When clicked on `'Start CPU Usage Profiling'` it wanted to restart the IDE, but it doesn't worked out. The IDE was shutdown but didnt start up again.

Even launching intellij manually nothing happens (doesn't even appear in the running processes list)

There are no logs neither in the intellij folder (INTELLI_HOME/system/logs) nor in windows events

But got this strange log in USER/.yjp/log:

```
17.02-66 0.002: Log file: C:\Users\user1\.yjp\log\idea64.exe-5592.log
17.02-66 0.002: Command line:
  C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\bin\idea64.exe
17.02-66 0.002: Executable: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\bin\idea64.exe
17.02-66 0.002: Windows 10; version 10.0.17763; 64-bit process
17.02-66 0.004: hid: 16022D097Y658WWZZV059787WX0X9U16284ZV8VUV4 64-bit machine
17.02-66 0.004: Today is 20210922
17.02-66 0.004: full_build_stamp: 2017.02.66 201709051525
17.02-66 0.004: Agent library path: C:\Users\user1\.IdeaIC2019.3\config\yk-binaries\yjpagent64.dll
17.02-66 0.004: getTimeNsInfo: "PerformanceFrequency=10000000"
17.02-66 0.004: Agent_OnLoad: orig_options=delay=10000,disable_async_sampling,disablealloc,onlylocal,probe_disable=*
  full_options=delay=10000,disable_async_sampling,disablealloc,onlylocal,probe_disable=*
17.02-66 0.005: phase: 1
17.02-66 0.005: jvmtiVersion: 300B0000
17.02-66 0.005: vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
17.02-66 0.005: version: 11.0.4+10-b520.11
17.02-66 0.005: info: mixed mode, aot, sharing
17.02-66 0.005: isJava6: 1
17.02-66 0.005: warning: probe com.yourkit.probes.builtin.AsyncChannels is not supported on Java 6
17.02-66 0.005: warning: probe com.yourkit.probes.builtin.AsyncChannels is not supported on Java 6
17.02-66 0.005: Cannot start: invalid option: disable_async_sampling
```

This seems totally invalid because I don't use java6 but java11 and everything (including JAVA_HOME) is correctly set. I never ever had java6 on this machine.

**edit:**
By removing `'disable_async_sampling'` flag from `idea64.exe.vmoptions` I was able to start up the IDE again. But of course the CPU profiling won't work in this case.

Comment: CPU usage profiling does not support application restart, as it records the process information. 
I'd recommend to update IntelliJ IDEA to 2021.2 where a lot of performance issues were fixed.

Comment: @Konstantin Annikov
The above mentioned official guide says it will ask for restart. And indeed it did.

Comment: Restart is only needed to add required VM options. CPU profiler is stopped once IDE closes